# How can I use Solaris::Kstat on Solaris 5.10?

Tags: perl, module, sunos, kstat

I am looking to find the SunOS system details using Kstat. I have found [Solaris::Kstat](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Solaris::Kstat) module in CPAN but this only supports Solaris 2.5.1, 2.6 & 2.7. [The Sun developer's site](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/kstat_part2.html) mentions a Sun::Solaris::Kstat which I have not found in CPAN. Can anyone please help me with the Perl scripting to find details from kstat on Solaris 5.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Brendan Gregg](http://www.brendangregg.com/k9toolkit.html) who actually develops Perl tools to work with Solaris systems:

> The KStat perl library is shipped with
>   Solaris.

However, in one of his modules he includes the following note:

```
# - If you have upgraded /usr/bin/perl, this program may be unable to 
#   find the Sun::Solaris::Kstat library (which is under /usr/perl5).
#   Before the "use strict;" line, you may need to add,
#   use lib "/usr/perl5/5.6.1/lib";
#   to point to your location of Sun/Solaris/Kstat.pm.
```

If that doesn't work, you may want to run a `find` command for `Kstat.pm`, to be certain of whether or not this file exists anywhere on your system.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I have found this at the same path you gave but when using this this path in my script i get the same error "Can't locate loadable object for module Sun::Solaris::Kstat". Please suggest.

Comment: @Virus:  That module has to do with loading the C libraries necessary for Kstat.  The error message itself should tell you the name of the particular file (usually ending in `.so` or `.o`).  You need to find that find on your system, and then add its path to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` enviroment variable, or modify `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `ldconfig` with root priviledge to modify the system-wide library configuration.